# Typo3 BE : No module "" could be found

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-4.5

I've upgraded one of typo3 module from 4.1 to 6.2 when I switch the module back end options from dropdown. The error comes. Any Idea please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a couple days of research. I got the solution for this.

The issue is occured because in the Iframe url: parameter 'M' {Module Name} was not generated.[you could able to see the complete url by view frame in new window]

This was due to a mis configuration that doesn't support in TYPO3 6.2

I've changed conf.php and index.php in TYPO3 Module Folder.

### 1.In conf.php

```
OLD : $MCONF['script']='index.php';

CHANGE : $MCONF["script"]="_DISPATCH";
```

### 2.In index.php

### OLD CODE

```
unset($MCONF);
require ("conf.php");
require ($BACK_PATH."init.php");
require_once($BACK_PATH.'template.php');
require_once (PATH_t3lib."class.t3lib_scbase.php");
$LANG->includeLLFile("EXT:extension_name/mod1/locallang.php");
$BE_USER->modAccess($MCONF,1);
```

### NEW CODE

```
unset($MCONF);
require ("conf.php");
//Comment----------require ($BACK_PATH."init.php");
//Comment----------require_once($BACK_PATH.'template.php');
//Comment----------require_once (PATH_t3lib."class.t3lib_scbase.php");
/*
* Changed $LANG to $GLOBALS['LANG'] 
* Changed $BE_USER to $GLOBALS['BE_USER']
*/

$GLOBALS['LANG']->includeLLFile('EXT:wf_tagcloud_bl/mod1/locallang.xml');
$GLOBALS['BE_USER']->modAccess($MCONF,1);
```